# Pass URL as a report parameter in SSRS

Tags: url, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to include a URL with other parameters in a report? I would like users to have ability to click on a link to view another report while passing various parameters to the report. Any recommendations will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Just add a textbox and set some value, then right click the textbox and select `Action` tab.

In Action tab select `Go to report` and choose the report you want to the URL point to. Then click add to specify the `Name` of parameters and its `Value`.

[image]

Hopefully this is what you are looking for, otherwise let me know.

Comment: I am actually trying to create the textbox in the parameter section, rather than the actual report. Is that possible?

Comment: Just create a new parameter and set text data type. It will appears in the parameter section.

Comment: Tried this; it won't let users click on the link.

Comment: I don't get your specific requeriment, edit your question to detail what you need.

Comment: I am basically trying to include a URL link in the parameter section that users can click on to open a new report.

Comment: In order to add a link in the parameters panel you have to programmatically customize the report viewer. There are a lot of examples out there. However, I think you don't need to do that after all. I suggest you put the links in the header of the report.